# AFNetworking Data Fetching Method Not Called

Tags: objective-c, ios, rest, asynchronous, afnetworking

I am creating an app where in the first view, the user is given the option to log-in or register. In the register view is a `UITableViewCell` that, when clicked, takes the user to a view containing a `UITableView` and a `UIPickerView`. The `UITableView` is working correctly, but the `UIPickerView`, which is supposed to dynamically pull the data it is supposed to display using a web call, is showing up but appears completely blank. Putting in a few `NSLog` statements, I noticed that the methods in the Model that pull the data using `AFNetworking` are never getting called. I've posted the code below for the `UIPickerViewDelegate` and `UIPickerViewDataSource` methods, as well as the method that is supposed to pull the data in the Model. Thanks in advance.

**UIPickerViewDelegate**

```
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row 
            forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return [[self.brain classChoicesForSignUp] objectAtIndex:row];
}
```

**UIPickerViewDataSource**

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView 
numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    size_t numberOfRows = [self.brain classChoicesForSignUp].count;

    NSLog(@"Number of Rows: %@", [[NSNumber numberWithFloat:numberOfRows] stringValue]);

    return numberOfRows;
}
```

**SignUpPickerBrain.m**

```
#import "SignUpPickerBrain.h"
#import "AFJSONRequestOperation.h"

@implementation SignUpPickerBrain

#pragma mark - Picker Data

- (NSArray *)classChoicesForSignUp {
    NSLog(@"Class choices method called");
    // Note that in my code, the actual URL is present here.
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"the URL"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
        NSLog(@"Success!");
        NSLog([JSON description]);
    } failure:nil];

    [operation start];
    [operation waitUntilFinished];
    NSLog([operation responseJSON]);
    return [operation responseJSON];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of anti-patterns going on in this code sample. I strongly recommend against your current approach, and consider the following points:

- Do networking **asynchronously**, i.e. don't use `[operation waitUntilFinished];`. Any time you're creating a method that makes a network request, give it a block parameter that can be used as a callback once the results come in.
- Store your results in an array property in the controller, or the like, and use that to drive your delegates and datasources. In your current approach, you will be doing a network request every single time a row is displayed (!). So instead, initialize to an empty array, and once the new results are set to that property, reload the data source. One asynchronous request. Easy.
- Get rid of `SignUpPickerBrain`. Either use a proper Model, or just make the call itself in the Controller. The example iOS project has some great patterns to follow.
- Use `AFHTTPClient`. If you're interacting with a particular webservice, it can be very useful to have an `AFHTTPClient` subclass to handle all of those requests.

Comment: Thanks so much for your response. I have a couple of questions, though. I thought that when you are dealing with fetching data and things like that, you use a file like `SignUpPickerBrain`. Could you elaborate a bit more on what you mean by a "proper Model"? I'm also a little confused as to why I would give a block parameter to the network request method, as I'm not doing anything but returning the data. I'm pretty new to blocks, though, so that could easily be the reason why I'm not seeing the utility here. Thanks again for all of your recommendations.

Comment: The block passed as a method parameter would be executed in the completion (or success/failure) block of the network request operation. This way it's asynchronous. Again, check out the iOS example project in AFNetworking to see this in action.